# Does xlwings require an excel install

Tags: python-2.7, xlwings

Does xlwings require an install of excel?

We are hoping to use it, with an anaconda install, on a windows server, with no EXCEL, to inject some data to a workbook and pass the workbook back to the user.

Comment: Isn't xlwings for *interacting with* Excel (i.e. wouldn't it be pointless without Excel installed)?

Comment: So we want to take a pandas dataframe, inject it into workbook, that user has sent to us, then send the new workbook (ftp) to the user. User has Excel installed on their machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

xlwings is indeed made for interacting with a running instance of Excel and therefore does not run on Linux.

You will want to have a look into the pandas [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method or you may even want to use one of the underlying libraries directly that this method uses (`XlsxWriter`, `openpyxl` and `xlwt`).

In short, with pandas you can do:

```
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: Seems like this could be a little clearer in their docs / site (which is great btw!)  There's lots of mention of interacting with Excel, but perhaps as the authors are close to it they don't realise their unspoken assumptions

Comment: yeah, it's been on the list for quite some time: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/200

Comment: Meanwhile, you can install xlwings on Linux, as a backend for xlwings Server (self-hosted). Though it's still meant to interact from a running Excel session on your laptop or via Excel on the web.