# How to replace images path in xlsx with original images using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file where one field has an image path.
below is the sample excel file

[image: sample excel]

I have images in img folder.
How to replace the image column with original images using python(pandas or HTML method or any other method)?

can we use it with file:///[file_name] to get the image in browser and I see with HTML we get the images in excel how to implement with local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the files are `.png`, you could include something like this (assuming `img/...` is a valid folder path:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("files.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets("sheet_name")

# loop through cells in the column, expanding downwards from cell E2
for i, cell in enumerate(ws.range("E2").options(expand="vertical").value):
    # add pictures using the file path, and paste starting in column F, same row
    ws.pictures.add(cell+".png", anchor=ws.range("F"+str(i+2)))
```

This appends `".png"` to the end of the file path.

You can change the size too, see the [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Pictures.add).

Comment: import xlwings as xw

ws = xw.Book('files.xlsx')

# loop through cells in the column, expanding downwards from cell E2
for i, cell in enumerate(ws.range("E2").options(expand="vertical").value):
    # add pictures using the file path, and paste starting in column F, same row
    ws.pictures.add(cell+".png", anchor=ws.range("F"+str(i+2)))

Can you send me the full code please @Rawson

Comment: I have added the `ws` definition - it is just the sheet of the workbook.

Comment: File "d:\work\thum_file\.venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 530, in __init__
    self._xl = COMRetryObjectWrapper(DispatchEx("Excel.Application"))
  File "d:\work\thum_file\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 145, in DispatchEx
    dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Getting the following error

Comment: Which part of the code do you receive that error message for?  Are you able to run the first few lines, and `ws.range("E2").options(expand="vertical").value`?  If so, it is an error for `ws.pictures...`.

Comment: wb = xw.Book("files.xlsx") at this part itself I getting the error and I don't have ms office installed on my computer I see it depended on excel from this I understand DispatchEx("Excel.Application"))

Comment: Oh, right.  You can't use xlwings without Excel, see the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767813/does-xlwings-require-an-excel-install) by the developer.

Comment: Can you please send me the code in pandas or others that is not depeneded on excel